# How to choose between Convert and Select with LINQ to objects?

Tags: .net, type-conversion, linq-to-objects

LINQ to objects is my best friend. I am using often the ConvertAll extension method to achieve a conversion.

However I realize I can achieve the same by using the Select extension method.

For example, I have a ListView that displays a list of Alarm objects. I store the object itself in the Tag property of a ListView element. Then I retrieve the selection this way :

*Version with ConvertAll:*

```
public Alarm[] SelectedTags
{
    get
    {
        return AlarmListView
               .SelectedItems
               .OfType<ListViewItem>()
               .ToList().ConvertAll(i => i.Tag as Alarm)
               .ToArray();
    }
}
```

*Version with Select:*

```
public Alarm[] SelectedTags
{
    get
    {
        return AlarmListView
               .SelectedItems
               .OfType<ListViewItem>()
               .Select(i => i.Tag as Alarm)
               .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Personally I prefer `Select` because I can convert my collections easily without having to put them in a `List` and use `ConvertAll`. Anyway, both have certainly good reasons to exists.

**Is one better than the other ?** In which scenarios ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConvertAll` has been around since .Net 2.0, whereas LINQ is newer. `Select` appears to be more general, and to make `ConvertAll` redundant.

I can't think of any situation where you would need to use `ConvertAll` in new code. `Select` is better-known, more general, and works with the other features of LINQ (such as direct translation to SQL queries in LINQ to SQL).

Comment: I realize now I believed wrongly that ConvertAll was a part of LINQ to Object. Thanks a lot for your clarification.